# How to get User details using Team Foundation Server (TFS) java SDK

Tags: java, tfs

I am trying to access TFS user details(profile details) for all the user who performed activities in TFS server. currently I am getting only user Display name using 'Assigned To' or 'Created By' fields.

I am trying to get user identity using following code.

```
IIdentityManagementService  identityManagementService = (IIdentityManagementService)tpc.getConfigurationServer().getWebService(IdentityManagementService.class);
TeamFoundationIdentity UserID = identityManagementService.readIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    "Chunky Garg", MembershipQuery.DIRECT, ReadIdentityOptions.EXTENDED_PROPERTIES);
```

Using above code i end up in following Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.tfs.core.config.webservice.UnknownWebServiceException: Unknown web service: [com.microsoft.tfs.core.clients.webservices.IdentityManagementService]
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.config.webservice.DefaultWebServiceFactory.newWebService(DefaultWebServiceFactory.java:226)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.TFSConnection.getWebService(TFSConnection.java:891)
    at tfs.TFSTest.main(TFSTest.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Please let me know if this a bug is java SDK or am i doing something wrong.

TFS version - using cloud version
JAVA SDK - 12.0.2
OS : MacOSX

Comment: Use the below code to fix this issue

IdentityManagementService identityManagementService=new IdentityManagementService(tpc);

TeamFoundationIdentity UserID = identityManagementService.readIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.DISPLAY_NAME, "Chunky Garg", MembershipQuery.DIRECT, ReadIdentityOptions.EXTENDED_PROPERTIES);